# wpa_supplicant working on specific channel for 802.11ac

Tags: networking, wireless, wpa-supplicant, hostapd

I have `QCA6174 802.11ac` Wireless Network Adapter in my laptop which runs Ubuntu 16.10 with Linux Kernel Version 4.13. The wireless adapter uses `ath10k` driver. I am trying to set the laptop to work as an access point using 802.11ac. To do that I am using `wpa_supplicant` with the following configuration file:

```
network={
    frequency=5180
    ssid="Test"
    mode=2
    key_mgmt=NONE
    disable_ht=1
    disable_vht=0
}
```

The previous configuration works perfectly and when I scan the spectrum I find the above SSID in my list of APs. However, if I change the frequency to a different channel for example [60] i.e. 5300 MHz instead of [36] i.e. 5180 MHz, the wpa_supplicant executes correctly but I do not see the SSID. So am I missing any configuration?

I tried to use `hostapd`, with the following configuration:

```
interface=wlan1
driver=nl80211
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd

ssid=travelmate

hw_mode=a
channel=36
ht_capab=[HT40+]
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211ac=1
vht_oper_chwidth=1
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
```

But I get the following error on all the channels:

```
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Configured channel (36) not found from the channel list of current mode (2) IEEE 802.11a
wlan1: IEEE 802.11 Hardware does not support configured channel
Could not select hw_mode and channel. (-3)
wlan1: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
wlan1: Unable to setup interface.
wlan1: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
wlan1: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan1 wasn't started
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan1 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

Which has something to do with the regulatory domain. So how I can solve the above problems?

Here is more additional information:

**1. Regulatory domain:**

```
iw reg get

country US: DFS-FCC
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 17), (N/A)
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)

dmesg | grep EEPROM

[    9.056790] ath: EEPROM regdomain: 0x6c
[    9.056791] ath: EEPROM indicates we should expect a direct regpair map
```

**2. Supported Channels in the 5 GHz band by my adapter:**

```
        * 5180 MHz [36] (17.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5200 MHz [40] (17.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5220 MHz [44] (17.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5240 MHz [48] (17.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5260 MHz [52] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5280 MHz [56] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5300 MHz [60] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5320 MHz [64] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5500 MHz [100] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5520 MHz [104] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5540 MHz [108] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5560 MHz [112] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5580 MHz [116] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5600 MHz [120] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5620 MHz [124] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5640 MHz [128] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5660 MHz [132] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5680 MHz [136] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5700 MHz [140] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5720 MHz [144] (23.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
          DFS state: usable (for 208 sec)
          DFS CAC time: 60000 ms
        * 5745 MHz [149] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5765 MHz [153] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5785 MHz [157] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5805 MHz [161] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5825 MHz [165] (30.0 dBm) (no IR)
        * 5845 MHz [169] (disabled)
```